# Dynamically Update Resource file in Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, embedded-resource, resx

I have Asp.net MVC as a Class library. All of my .resx files are also in the same class library project as Embedded resource. So basically ill get output as a dll
And my requirement is that i need a page where i can get all the key value pair from the .resx files from the dll (which is bit easy) and again update the resx in the dll to reflect the changes on screen.

So the basic idea is I need a page where i can dynamically update the .resx file which are avaliable as the external class library. And the updated resources must be seen 'AS UPDATED' wherever needed.

Any Kind suggestions or some other working approach heartly welcomed.

Comment: Not sure if that is possible, what about using a DB?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1869308.aspx?Update+Resx+file+at+runtime